# Как перемещать дочерний объект и не выходить за блок?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.right_img{
    display: inline-block;
    display: block;

}

.right_img a{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 8em;
    top: 95%;
    left: 47%;

}
```

```html
<div class="promo-4_5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row img-wrap ">
                <div class="left_img ml-auto mr-4">
                    <img src="../../../static/img/promo-4.jpg" class="img_left mx-auto d-block ">
                    <a type="button">Купить сейчас</a>
                </div>
                <div class="right_img mr-auto">
                    <img src="../../../static/img/promo-5.jpg" class="img_left d-block">
                    <a type="button">Купить сейчас</a>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы кнопка была чуть выше конца картинки + по-центру картинки. Обернул картинку в div, чтобы равнять по родительскому блоку, но не выходит. Подскажите плиз, я только учусь

Comment: Родительскому блоку надо дать `position: relative;`

Comment: теперь кнопка не выходит за границы блока слева и справа, но наверх (на картинку) я не могу ее подвинуть

Answer (score 1):

Помимо top и left, еще существуют bottom и right. Кнопку любого размера можно поставить на N пикселей от нижней и правой сторон:

```css
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0; /* Это чтобы в div-блоке не было пробела под картинкой */
}

.img input[type="button"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-4_5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row img-wrap ">
      <div class="img left_img ml-auto mr-4">
        <img src="https://gyazo.com/d62d37422892495cbb27923348f668df.png" class="img_left mx-auto d-block ">
        <input type="button" value="Купить сейчас">
      </div>
      <div class="img right_img mr-auto">
        <img src="https://gyazo.com/92a8f48263dacbbd91628c4755ca9b0d.png" class="img_left d-block">
        <input type="button" value="Купить сейчас">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```